# ¿Cómo muestro una etiqueta nueva (<div></div>) al dar click en "submit" en mi formulario en php?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

¡Hola amigos! Una consulta, tengo mi código en HTML y en PHP, pero no logro hacer que al momento de dar click en "SUBMIT", al usuario le salga una alerta o un "div" nuevo que diga "MENSAJE ENVIADO CORRECTAMENTE", no quiero dirigirlo a una página diferente, quisiera que en la misma página salga ese mensaje, ya que al momento de dar en "submit", sólamente se recarga la página y causa confusión al usuario si se mandó el mensaje o no.

Este es mi código HTML:

```
<form action="contact.php" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" class="rd-mailform text-left offset-top-30">
                        <div class="range offset-top-0">
                            <div class="cell-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="contact-name" class="form-label form-label-outside">Nombre Completo<span class="text-primary">*</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" data-constraints="@Required" placeholder="Nombre Completo" class="form-control" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="contact-email" class="form-label form-label-outside">Email<span class="text-primary">*</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" data-constraints="@Required @Email" class="form-control" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="contact-phone" class="form-label form-label-outside">Teléfono</label>
                                    <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Teléfono" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group textarea-group">
                            <label for="contact-message" class="form-label form-label-outside">Mensaje<span class="text-primary">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Mensaje" data-constraints="@Required" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="offset-top-40 text-center">
                            <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="ENVIAR" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Ahora</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                        <!--<div class="mensajeEnviado"><label class="textoEnviado">¡Mensaje enviado correctamente, estaremos en contacto!<label></div>
                        </div> -->
```

Este es mi código PHP, pueden notar que el div de "¡Mensaje enviado correctamente" está como un comentario, ya que obviamente no quiero que salga en la página por default sin que el usuario haya hecho algo, me estuvieron diciendo que lo puedo hacer en "AJAX" para que no lo redirija a otra página, pero sinceramente no sé nada sobre AJAX, si existe la forma de hacerlo en php, les agradecería mucho su ayuda, igual me comentaron que hiciera un "if-else" para pasarlo a otras páginas, pero no creo que sea la mejor opción.

```
<?php

    $para = "luiz_naiper@hotmail.com, luan.ortodoncia@gmail.com";

    $asunto = "Mensaje desde la pag web";

    $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";      
    $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
    $MESSAGEBODY = "Nombre: ".$_POST["name"]."\n";
    $MESSAGEBODY .= "\n<br>Email: ".$_POST["email"]."\n";
    $MESSAGEBODY .= "\n<br>Teléfono: ".$_POST["phone"]."\n";
    $MESSAGEBODY .= "\n<br>Mensaje: ".($_POST["message"])."\n";

    mail($para, $asunto, $MESSAGEBODY, $mailheader) or die ("Error al enviar email");

    header("Location: http://www.luanclinicadental.com/contacto.html");


?>
```

Comment: bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, ¿A que te refieres con etiqueta de enviado y error? ¿mostrar un mensaje para cada caso?

Comment: Exactamente, pero no quiero un alert en javascript, podría ser un <div> bonito que solamente diga eso, de hecho en mi código de Jacascript, salía un mensaje de "ENVIANDO" y después se eliminó, ya ese no me interesa tanto, ya me quebré mucho la cabeza, sólamente sería el div de "ENVIADO", porque solamente se recarga la página y luego los usuarios no entienden, ya me han llegado varios correos del mismo usuario escribiendo lo mismo varias veces. ¡Gracias por tu respuesta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que usar ajax

```
<form onsubmit="return false;" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" class="rd-mailform text-left offset-top-30">
    <div class="range offset-top-0">
        <div class="cell-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contact-name" class="form-label form-label-outside">Nombre Completo<span class="text-primary">*</span></label>
                <input id="name" type="text" name="name" data-constraints="@Required" placeholder="Nombre Completo" class="form-control" required/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contact-email" class="form-label form-label-outside">Email<span class="text-primary">*</span></label>
                <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" data-constraints="@Required @Email" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contact-phone" class="form-label form-label-outside">Teléfono</label>
                <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Teléfono" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group textarea-group">
        <label for="contact-message" class="form-label form-label-outside">Mensaje<span class="text-primary">*</span></label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Mensaje" data-constraints="@Required" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="offset-top-40 text-center">
        <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="ENVIAR" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitForm()">Enviar Ahora</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Agrega jquery

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js'></script>
```

Y este script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(){
        if($('input#name').val()==""){
            alert('Introduzca un nombre');
            return false;
        }
        if($('input#email').val()==""){
            alert('Introduzca un email');
            return false;
        }
        if($('input#phone').val()==""){
            alert('Introduzca un telefono');
            return false;
        }
        if($('#message').val()==""){
            alert('Escriba un mensaje');
            return false;
        }
            var form = $('#form1');
            var data = form.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : 'contact.php',
                data: data,
                success: function(){
                    form.find('.alert').remove();
                    form.append('<div class="alert alert-success">El mensaje ha sido enviado correctamente</div>');
                    form.find('.alert').show();
                }
            });


    }
</script>
```

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.luanclinicadental.com/contacto.html' (redirected from 'http://luanclinicadental.com/contact.php') from origin 'http://luanclinicadental.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Me sale eso amigo :(

Comment: quita en el php

Comment: Esto : header("Location: http://www.luanclinicadental.com/contacto.html");

Comment: Sí me llega el mensaje a la bandeja de correo una vez que le quité eso, pero ahora me sale "Uncaught TypeError: form.find is not a function
    at Object.success (contacto.html:386)
    at c (core.min.js:7)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (core.min.js:7)
    at n (core.min.js:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.t (core.min.js:7)"

Comment: Y la alerta no sale aún :( el div

Comment: Ah perdona error garrafal mio, ahora te actualizo en 2 min la respuesta

Comment: Actualizado....

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: formdata is not defined
    at submitForm (contacto.html:385)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (contacto.html:262)

Comment: Amigo solo he cambiado el script.

Comment: Copia bien el codigo.

Comment: Mil gracias, ahora sí salió :D Te lo agradezco infinitamente!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: ¿Qué crees amigazo? Sale bien el código y todo, pero ahora sale "Mensaje enviado correctamente" aunque no pongan los campos, etc. Me refiero, con el simple hecho de dar click, sale la alerta, ¿Habrá forma de arreglarlo?

Comment: Ya tienes el script actualizado.

Comment: ¡Buenos días! Ahora no sale el mensaje de "enviado correctamente", además, en el correo no me llegan los datos, sólamente me llega "MENSAJE DE: DESCONOCIDO: NOMBRE: EMAIL: TEL:" etc, no me llega el .val() del usuario, igual que:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: form.find is not a function
    at Object.success (contacto.html:392)
    at c (core.min.js:7)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (core.min.js:7)
    at n (core.min.js:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.t (core.min.js:7)

Comment: Copia de nuevo el script, de nuevo cometí el mismo error de la vez pasada.

Comment: ¡Súper! Ya está arreglado todo el front, ahora en la parte del back no entiendo por qué se manda vacío, no me salen los datos del usuario en mi correo, se me hace raro porque del php lo único que borré fue lo que me comentaste de "header"

Comment: joder jaja, espera, otro error mio, me falto el type en el ajax, copia el script nuevamente, en  1 minuto

Comment: hahaha mil gracias, espero aprender pronto a hacer eso, saludos!! Ya quedó todo al 100%, te comparto el url www.luanclinicadental.com/contacto.html

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres en si ? Tienes dos opciones mandar el form mediante ajax luego limpiar el formulario y mostrar el div con el mensaje que quieres o puedes enviar con php mandarlo a otra pagina o la misma y mostrar el mensaje

1. [php-flash-messages](https://mikeeverhart.net/php-flash-messages/)
2. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/alerts/

Comment: Sí, justamente quiero que al momento de dar click en "submit", salga un mensaje que diga "Mensaje enviado correctamente", porque ahorita la dar "submit", sólamente se recarga la página y el usuario no sabe si el mensaje se envió o no :( Pero sigo sin poder hacerlo jaja